# cannot run rust PrimitiveDateTime example

Tags: date, datetime, rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to solve a very simple rust exercise involving `PrimitiveDateTime`. I'm trying to run this [basic example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Ballow(unused)%5D%0Aextern%20crate%20r%23time%3B%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0Ause%20time%3A%3A%7BPrimitiveDateTime%2C%20macros%3A%3A%7Bdate%2C%20datetime%2C%20time%7D%7D%3B%0Aassert_eq!(%0A%20%20%20%20PrimitiveDateTime%3A%3Anew(date!(2019-01-01)%2C%20time!(0%3A00))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20datetime!(2019-01-01%200%3A00)%2C%0A)%3B%0A%7D&edition=2018) in my own machine

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
extern crate r#time;

fn main() {
    use time::{
        macros::{date, datetime, time},
        PrimitiveDateTime,
    };
    assert_eq!(
        PrimitiveDateTime::new(date!(2019 - 01 - 01), time!(0:00)),
        datetime!(2019-01-01 0:00),
    );
}
```

It compile on the [rust playground,](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Ballow(unused)%5D%0Aextern%20crate%20r%23time%3B%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0Ause%20time%3A%3A%7BPrimitiveDateTime%2C%20macros%3A%3A%7Bdate%2C%20datetime%2C%20time%7D%7D%3B%0Aassert_eq!(%0A%20%20%20%20PrimitiveDateTime%3A%3Anew(date!(2019-01-01)%2C%20time!(0%3A00))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20datetime!(2019-01-01%200%3A00)%2C%0A)%3B%0A%7D&edition=2018) but it gives me the following errors on my machine:

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling playground v0.1.0 (/home/sas/exercism/rust/playground)
error[E0432]: unresolved imports `time::macros`, `time::PrimitiveDateTime`, `time::macros::date`, `time::macros::datetime`
 --> src/main.rs:4:12
  |
4 | use time::{PrimitiveDateTime, macros::{date, datetime, time}};
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^   ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
  |                               |
  |                               could not find `macros` in `time`

error: cannot find macro `date` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:28
  |
6 |     PrimitiveDateTime::new(date!(2019-01-01), time!(0:00)),
  |                            ^^^^

error: cannot determine resolution for the macro `time`
 --> src/main.rs:6:47
  |
6 |     PrimitiveDateTime::new(date!(2019-01-01), time!(0:00)),
  |                                               ^^^^
  |
  = note: import resolution is stuck, try simplifying macro imports

error: cannot find macro `datetime` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     datetime!(2019-01-01 0:00),
  |     ^^^^^^^^

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `PrimitiveDateTime`
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     PrimitiveDateTime::new(date!(2019-01-01), time!(0:00)),
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
  |
help: consider importing this struct
  |
3 | use time::PrimitiveDateTime;
  |

error[E0659]: `time` is ambiguous (name vs any other name during import resolution)
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use time::{PrimitiveDateTime, macros::{date, datetime, time}};
  |     ^^^^ ambiguous name
  |
note: `time` could refer to the unresolved item imported here
 --> src/main.rs:4:56
  |
4 | use time::{PrimitiveDateTime, macros::{date, datetime, time}};
  |                                                        ^^^^
note: `time` could also refer to the crate imported here
 --> src/main.rs:2:1
  |
2 | extern crate r#time;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = help: use `::time` to refer to this crate unambiguously
  = help: or use `crate::time` to refer to this crate unambiguously

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0432, E0433, E0659.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 6 previous errors
```

This is my Cargo.toml file:

```
[package]
name = "playground"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
time = "0.3.5"
```

I'd like to know how to solve it and to understand the error it throws. It seems like some conflict between the `time` crate and the macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a few things in the `time` crate are feature flag gated, meaning you need to manually specify some feature to enable a certain feature. In your case the macros are missing, taking a look at [`time`'s crates.io page](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/) shows us you need to add the feature `macros` to enable this. You can do this by specifying your dependency like so:

```
[dependencies]
time = { version = "0.3.5", features = ["macros"] }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just looked the PrimitiveDateTime::new function docs (https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.PrimitiveDateTime.html#impl) but failed to look the macros docs (https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/macros/macro.time.html) which clearly states that it needs the macros feature.